# cleveref for theorems with same type

Tags: cleveref, ntheorem

I usually create theorem environments in pairs - one uses the ordinary theorem style, the other (whose name starts with a capital letter) uses the "break" style, which inserts a line break before the theorem text. This is very useful for theorems with long texts or long names. `cleveref` seems to support this well, at least for references to individual theorems. However, `\crefrange` cannot see that the two theorems have the same type (see below).

I know there is a workaround using `aliascnt`; however, I would like to involve as few packages as possible for dealing with references, in order to keep things simple and avoid bugs. Also, using `aliascnt` is a slightly "ugly" solution that involves a lot of code if you use many different theorem types. **Can someone provide me with a solution that does not involve `aliascnt`, but which (preferably) only uses `ntheorem` and `cleveref`?**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem,cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{Thm}[thm]{Theorem}

\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}\label{thm:short}
        Theorem with short text.
    \end{thm}

    \begin{Thm}[The well-ordering theorem]\label{thm:long}
        Theorem with long text.
    \end{Thm}

    \cref{thm:short}

    \cref{thm:long}

    \crefrange{thm:short}{thm:long}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cleveref` provides `\crefalias`

```
\crefalias{Thm}{thm}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem,cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{Thm}[thm]{Theorem}

\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefalias{Thm}{thm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}\label{thm:short}
        Theorem with short text.
    \end{thm}

    \begin{Thm}[The well-ordering theorem]\label{thm:long}
        Theorem with long text.
    \end{Thm}

    \cref{thm:short}

    \cref{thm:long}

    \crefrange{thm:short}{thm:long}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

P.S. If you want the endash for conjuction, add the line

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Bonus question: **Why does `hyperref` break it?** (Just inser `hyperref` between `ntheorem` and `cleveref`, where you are usually adviced to put it).

Comment: @Gaussler -- that's a really good question.  if you haven't done so already, post it as a new question, with a link back to this one.

Comment: I have done so now: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230951/error-hyperref-breaks-crefalias