# Error (?): hyperref breaks \crefalias

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, ntheorem

The below code (exluding the line `\usepackage{hyperref}`) provides two theorem environments `thm` and `Thm`, which use two different theorem styles (with andwithout a line break right after the theorem numbers, respectively). However, if I load `hyperref` (before `cleveref`, as the manual for the latter package tells me to do), the `\crefrange` on the last line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- this line breaks \crefrange
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{Thm}[thm]{Theorem}

\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefalias{Thm}{thm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}\label{thm:short}
        Theorem with short text.
    \end{thm}

    \begin{Thm}[The well-ordering theorem]\label{thm:long}
        Theorem with long text.
    \end{Thm}

    \cref{thm:short}

    \cref{thm:long}

    \crefrange{thm:short}{thm:long}
\end{document}
```

Without `hyperref`:

[image]

With `hyperref`:

[image]

When I insert `\usepackage{hyperref}`, I actually get a lot of errors the first time I compile. However, compiling the second time, this is reduced to

> LaTeX Warning: References `thm:short` and `thm:long` in reference range on page
>    1 have different types `thm` and `Thm` on input line 27.

Can anyone find this error and (preferably) find a way to solve it?

*This question relates to [cleveref for theorems with same type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230912/cleveref-for-theorems-with-same-type/230920#230920)*.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it's better to send some information to the maintainers of both `cleveref` and `hyperref`. Heiko 'Mr. Hyperref' Oberdiek is a user here, but I am unsure about Toby Cubitt

Comment: [Toby Cubitt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27827/toby-cubitt) is a contributor to this site as well; see, e.g., [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145356/5001) to the question "Crossreference in Ref Range [(1a-1e) to (1a-e)]".

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for `excavation` of Toby... unfortunately, he does not seem to be very active here :-(

Comment: I couldn't find Oberdiek's e-mail, can anyone help me? :-)

Comment: Changing the order of loading (`hyperref` before `cleveref`) seems to fix a similar problem for me, based on this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113726/8666

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis According to the `cleveref` manual, `cleveref` *has* to be loaded after all other reference-releated packages, including `hyperref`. I have not checked what happens if I change the order, and I won't because it is likely to cause other problems. By the way, Toby Cubitt has reported that he has fixed the error, so the issue will be solved in an upcoming release.

Comment: For the record, this is indeed fixed in recent cleveref versions.

Comment: @TobyCubitt I checked CTAN, but it seems the package has not been updated since 2013.

Comment: @Gaussler The CTAN version is indeed quite old. Newer "pre-release" versions are available from my web site: http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.html I urgently need to update the version on CTAN, but I'd like to do a bit more testing of the latest pre-release before I do so, as it overhauls quite a lot of the internal code.

Comment: @TobyCubitt The link you provided is dead.

Comment: @Gaussler Thanks for the heads-up. Should be back up now.

Answer (score 7):

The `cleveref` package adds an optional argument to the `\label` command, specifying to which 'driver' counter a label should belong. Alternatively, one could use the `aliascnt` approach as described in the `cleveref` manual, see page 9 of the PDF doc.

Since this approach is not necessary if `hyperref` is not included, there seems to some incompatibility or a bug. My 'solution' is a workaround and not more.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- this line breaks \crefrange

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{Thm}[thm]{Theorem}

\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefalias{Thm}{thm}


\begin{document}
    \begin{thm} \label{thm:short}
        Theorem with short text.
    \end{thm}

    \begin{Thm}[The well-ordering theorem]\label[thm]{thm:long}
        Theorem with long text.
    \end{Thm}

    \cref{thm:short}

    \cref{thm:long}

    \crefrange{thm:short}{thm:long}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd better report that bug somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You may have discovered a bug in `cleveref`'s `\crefalias` macro and/or in `hyperref`. A remedy would be *not* to use the `\crefalias` device; instead, set `\crefname{Thm}{theorem}{theorems}` in the preamble and use `\label[thm]{thm:long}`, i.e., set the optional argument to `\label` that specifies the counter type to be used for `cleveref`'s cross-referencing work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}  
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{Thm}[thm]{Theorem}

\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{Thm}{theorem}{theorems} % new

\begin{document}    
\begin{thm}\label{thm:short}
No line break after header.
\end{thm}

\begin{Thm}[The well-ordering theorem] \label[thm]{thm:long}
Line break after header.
\end{Thm}

    \cref{thm:short}, \cref{thm:long}

    \cref{thm:short,thm:long}

    \crefrange{thm:short}{thm:long}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would seem there is no better solution, unfortunately. Thanks for your answer.