# Referencing theorems (while including the theorem caption)

Tags: theorems, automation, ref

I would like to cite my Theorems with the kind of Theorem (Corollary, Proposition, etc...). Actually when I refer to a theorem I have to type `Theorem \ref{name}`. 
I have seen in few papers that it is possible to avoid 'Theorem' and juste type `\ref{name}`. Cleveref doesn't work well since I use ntheorem.

But I found a solution here [cleveref for theorems with same type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230912/cleveref-for-theorems-with-same-type)

for the users of ntheorem. However it doesn't work well in the following minimal example and I'm not able to find the error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}  % Helvetica, scaled 92%
\usepackage{courier}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}%symboles maths,polices loc différentes 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,backref=page]{hyperref}


%Théorèmes
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}


{\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremindent0cm
\theorempreskip{0.8cm}
\theorempostskip{0.8cm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem –}[section]
\crefname{theo}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefalias{theo}{Theorem}}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=Green,linkcolor=Red, urlcolor=Green}


\begin{theo}[Existence and uniqueness (1)]\label{existuniq1}
Let $m >1$. 

\end{theo}


 \cref{existuniq1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this depends on what document class and packages you are using.  this question might be helpful: [amsthm with shared counters messes up autoref references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187388/579)

Comment: You should take a look at the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Or `fancyref`. @

Answer (score 1):

Astonishingly, it seems that this very basic question has not been asked in this form here yet. So here is an answer:

A choice might be the `cleveref` package.

> The cleveref package enhances LATEX’s cross-referencing features, allowing the format of cross-references to be determined automatically according to the “type” of cross-reference (equation, section, etc.) and the context in which the cross-reference is used.

<sub>(from the package documentation)</sub>

The `cleveref` package might even be the best choice. It behaves well in most situations and, for instance, the issue mentioned by @barbarabeeton is easily fixed using `cleveref`.

Assuming you set up a theorem environment like

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

then you would reference it (getting the theorem caption "for free") with the `\cref` command. (The `theorem` environment can be also defined via `ntheorem`.)

```
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:foo}
Foo bar.
\end{theorem}

\cref{thm:foo}
```

[image: showcase]

The cpation is typeset uppercase when toggling the 'capitalize' option. The links are produced employing `hyperref` with options 'colorlinks' and 'linkcolor=DeepSkyBlue2' where 'DeepSkyBlue2' is a `x11names` color from `xcolor`. You finally need to specify the 'nameinlink' option in `cleveref` to get the reference colored completely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkcolor=DeepSkyBlue2,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:foo}
Foo bar.
\end{theorem}

\cref{thm:foo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly a *minimal* working example... (See [[1](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/)].)

Anyway, the problem is that you enclosed the lines

```
{\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremindent0cm
\theorempreskip{0.8cm}
\theorempostskip{0.8cm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem –}[section]
\crefname{theo}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefalias{theo}{Theorem}}
```

in curly brackets, thus forming a group. This means that any definitions made within this group will be *local* (i.e. only visible within the group), unless it is specified that the definition should be *global*. [[2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Global_definitions)]

The above refers to bare TeX definitions, i.e. `\def`, `\edef`, `\let` and such. More advanced LaTeX commands from included packages can also define various macros, which might be local or global, depending on the implementation of the package. Apparently commands like `\newtheorem` are global, but `\crefname` is local.

Remove the curly brackets to get the code working:

```
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremindent0cm
\theorempreskip{0.8cm}
\theorempostskip{0.8cm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem –}[section]
\crefname{theo}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefalias{theo}{Theorem}
```